# ESP32 I2C along with analogue read not working. How to fix it?

Tags: analog, i2c, freertos

First of all I am new to electronics. I am using ESP32 dev kit and trying to communicate with an i2c sensor and an analogue sensor.

I am able to communicate both devices.

I am using freertos Task to gather output running on parallel threads on two cores of the ESP32.

I noticed that as the I2C communication begins the noise in the analogue signal increase to every high level. I am completely puzzled why this is happening. Could it be ghosting, or something that I don't know about?

I need your guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Please note if the I2C device is not running then the analogue values are read perfectly.

Comment: Either : don't use I2C when reading analog, or : take a degree in Electronic Engineering and come back to this task. Otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: Don't have time for a degree too old for it now:) . Please give me a short answer or send me in the right direction. I really appreciate for your reply.

Comment: OK, here's the short answer: Henry W. Ott - "Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering"  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Electromagnetic-Compatibility-Engineering-Henry-Ott/dp/0470189304

Comment: This helps. Now I can see how can I eliminate electromagnetic interference , I need to design a circuit which can reduce it.  Thank you

Comment: did you tried to modify the attenuation parmeter of ADC ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue when I used BLE and analogread together.

Try the following function if you use arduino-core. 
Use `adc2_config_channel_atten` function ifyou are usung esp-idf

```
int new_analogRead(int pin){
  int value = 0;
  int8_t channel = digitalPinToAnalogChannel(pin);
  if(channel < 0){
      return 0;//not adc pin
  }
  if(channel > 7){    //ADC2
    adc2_config_channel_atten(adc2_channel_t(channel-10),ADC_ATTEN_11db);//11dB attenuation (ADC_ATTEN_11db) gives full-scale voltage 3.9V
    adc2_get_raw(adc2_channel_t(channel-10), ADC_WIDTH_BIT_10, &value);
    //used chanel-10 based on gpioMUX in esp32-hal-gpio
    return value;
  } else {//ADC1- not required
      // while (GET_PERI_REG_MASK(SENS_SAR_MEAS_START1_REG, SENS_MEAS1_DONE_SAR) == 0); //wait for conversion
      // value = GET_PERI_REG_BITS2(SENS_SAR_MEAS_START1_REG, SENS_MEAS1_DATA_SAR, SENS_MEAS1_DATA_SAR_S);
      return 0;
  }
}
```